# Не работает выпадающее меню HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

Всех приветствую, подскажите пожалуйста, пишу маленький блог, верстаю шапку, и не получается сделать выпадающее меню видимым при наведении мышки на кабинет. Прикреплю изображение того, как должно быть при ховере на элемент меню, а вот код:

```css
.header {
  background-color: #781414;
}

.header__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.header__list-link {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.header__list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.header__list-item :hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #520f0f;
}

.main {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

.user-panel {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 43px;
  right: 0px;
}

.user-panel__link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.account :hover .user-panel {
  display: flex;
}

.user-panel__link {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #520f0f;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header__logo">My Blog</h1>
<ul class="header__list">
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">О нас</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">Услуги</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link account"><i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-sm"></i> Кабинет</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header__list-item user-panel">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link user-panel__link">Админ панель</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link user-panel__link">Выход</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> не получается сделать выпадающее меню видимым при наведении мышки на кабинет

У тебя не особо удачное формирование ДОМ-дерева элементов и есть огрехи в стилях.

Предложу вот такой макет для формирования ДОМ-дерева ну и статейку по "выпадающим меню". https://dsgnmania.com/web-design/html-css/horizontal-dropdown/

```css
.header {
  background-color: #781414;
}

.header__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.header__list-link {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.header__list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.header__list-item:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #520f0f;
}

.main {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

.user-panel {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 43px;
  right: 0px;
}

.user-panel__link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.account:hover + .user-panel {
  display: flex;
}

.user-panel__link {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #520f0f;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header__logo">My Blog</h1>
<ul class="header__list">
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">О нас</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">Услуги</a>
  </li>
  <li class="header__list-item">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link account"><i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-sm"></i> Кабинет</a>
    <ul class="header__list-item user-panel">
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link user-panel__link">Админ панель</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link user-panel__link">Выход</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Добавил ваш код, где был добавлен + .user-panel, не работает :/

Comment: Хотя у вас в сниппете всё прекрасно работает, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: @Андрей, наверняка есть какая-то разница у примера и оригинала...

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить немножко иным способом, обернув в див как кнопку кабинет, так и кнопки меню.

```css
    .container {
  max-width: 1240px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: #781414;
}

.header__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.header__list-link {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.header__list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.header__list-item :hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #520f0f;
}

.main {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

.user-panel {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 43px;
  right: 0px;
}

.user-panel__link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown:hover .user-panel {
  display: flex;
}

.user-panel__link {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #520f0f;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__wrapper">
                <h1 class="header__logo">My Blog</h1>
                <ul class="header__list">
                    <li class="header__list-item">
                        <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">Главная</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__list-item">
                        <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">О нас</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__list-item">
                        <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link">Услуги</a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <li class="header__list-item account">
                            <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link "><i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-sm"></i> Кабинет</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="header__list-item user-panel">
                            <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link user-panel__link">Админ панель</a>
                            <a href="index.html" class="header__list-link user-panel__link">Выход</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: В место "обертки" `div` используй любой списочный тег `ul` или `ol` - так будет семантически вернее. Это же еще один список. ;)

Comment: Не дает писать короткие сообщения... Спасибо!